# Python "not in" not correctly identifying strings which do not contain a particular letter

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a little program to play the popular game, Wordle.

One of my function attempts to remove words from a word bank which do not contain a particular letter. The function does a decent job, but I have discovered that the function occasionally fails to identify words that should be removed from the list. If I call on the function repeatedly, it will eventually eliminate all the correct words.

```
#Creates a list of 4266 five-letter words from a text file
five_letters = open("five.txt", "r")
five = five_letters.read()
five = five.split()

#Iterates across list and removes words that do not contain a particular letter
def eliminate_words_not_containing(list, letter):
    for word in list:
        if letter not in word:
            list.remove(word)
    return list

# Call on the function 10 times and print the length of the list after each call
print(len(five))
for i in range(10):
    five = eliminate_words_not_containing(five, "e")
    print(len(five))
```

The output is:

```
4266
2932
2319
2070
2014
2010
2010
2010
2010
2010
2010
```

How can I write the function so that it catches all the words that do not containing a particular letter the first time through?

Silly question: Is it possible for the program to be running too quickly, and it skips over words?

Comment: Don't remove things from a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: The problem you are running into is that you are mutating the list of words as you are iterating over it.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: Do not iterate over mutable collections while simultaneously removing elements from them. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: "_Is it possible for the program to be running too quickly, and it skips over words?_" No.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, since Python uses that as the name of its constructor for a list.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You iterating over the original list, so when you remove one word the position isn't updated, try to make a copy of the list and iterate over it.

Edit: I'd try list comprehension if it was me so:

```
list = [word for word in list if letter not in word]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are modifying your list *while you are iterating over it*, you are skipping words.

If your list is `['word1', 'word2', 'word3']` and you call your eliminate function, you will be left with `['word2']` because you removed `'word1'`, then your for loop moved on to the 2nd index, which is now `'word3'` from the original list (with `'word2'` being the first word in the list after the removal of `'word1'`).

---

There are several ways to solve the problem, but one solution would be to remember the indices to remove:

```py
def eliminate_words_not_containing(word_list, letter):
    to_remove = set()
    for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
        if letter not in word:
            to_remove.add(i)
    return [word for i, word in enumerate(word_list) if i not in to_remove]
```

Probably just a regular list comprehension would be better in this case, but the above would be generalized in case you want to do something more complicated with each entry.

---

(Also, it's not good practice to use the variable named `list` because it clobbers the built-in type `list` in python.)